# How to reset permissions granted/denied to a pyinstaller executable?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, zoom-sdk, pywebview

I have created an app using pyinstaller that uses **pywebview** and Zoom Meeting SDK. When the user opens the Zoom Meeting for the first time in my app, it automatically asks for microphone and camera permission. If the user denies the permission, there is no way to enable the permission again. How can I ask for microphone and camera permission again? Or is there any way to clear that data so that the app asks for permission again?

Comment: Your question will receive a faster answer in the [Zoom Developer Forum](https://devforum.zoom.us/)

Comment: Assuming that that data is _in_ the executable, rather than metadata attached to the executable via xattrs or a registry entry keyed by a hash or the name of the executable is... certainly an assumption.

Comment: And how this is done is different between operating systems; the question needs to describe which one you're talking about.

Comment: I am using Windows OS. Actually, I tried to delete the app and rebuild completely pyinstaller, but no effect